# docker + haproxy on mac 10.11.5 doesn't work

Tags: macos, docker, haproxy

I am running an haproxy configuration on mac that works perfect on linux but I can't get the proxy to even respond. Here is my config:

```
defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 5000ms
    timeout server 5000ms

frontend http
    bind *:80
    acl oracle_content hdr(ContentType) -i  application/vnd.api+json
    acl oracle_accept hdr(Accept) -i  application/vnd.api+json
    use_backend oracle_be    if oracle_content
    use_backend oracle_be    if oracle_accept
    default_backend matrix_be


backend oracle_be
   balance roundrobin
   server oracle1 theoracle.stage.company.com:8080

backend matrix_be
   balance roundrobin
   server matrix1 192.168.1.6:3000
```

> docker run -d --name cc -v /Users/cbongiorno/development/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro haproxy

```
docker -v

Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
```

the only machine specific config is the IP adress of the matrix_be entry which has to be my local interface. It's not working on 2 macs and I have tried binding the proxy to multiple interfaces. I am not even getting a 504 which would indicate the proxy is fine but one of the backend services is misconfigured.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Due to current docker on mac [limitations](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/), the -p 80:80 flag must be passed even if the container declares port 80 open for business